# Bootstrap layout logically correct but renders weird

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, layout

I am designing a Bootstrap grid and want it to change on different view sizes.

The code I use is included here:

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-12 col-lg-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
            <h3>فرم اطلاعات کاربر</h3>
            <hr>
            <fieldset>
                <legend>گروه اول</legend>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-sm-push-6 col-md-3 col-md-push-9">
                            <label for="name">نام</label>
                            <input type="text" name="name" placeholder="نام" class="form-control">
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-sm-pull-6 col-md-3 col-md-pull-0 col-md-push-3">
                            <label for="family">نام خانوادگی</label>
                            <input type="text" name="family" placeholder="نام خانوادگی" class="form-control">
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-sm-push-6 col-md-3 col-md-pull-3 col-md-push-0">
                            <label for="name">نام پدر</label>
                            <input type="text" name="father-name" placeholder="نام پدر" class="form-control">
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-sm-pull-6 col-md-3 col-md-pull-9">
                            <label for="family">شماره شناسنامه</label>
                            <input type="text" name="id-number" placeholder="شماره شناسنامه" class="form-control">
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </fieldset>

        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

and I also created a Bootply here: [Code Sample](http://www.bootply.com/116861)

As you can see in the link above, the 3rd column when the view is in MD mode, pulled 3 columns and because it has been pushed in the SM mode, I reset the push on MD mode, but although the css right is being set on the column but it doesn't move to the right place.

Does anyone know how to fix this please?

**Update:** I also have to mention that, I want my layout to be right to left and that's the reason why I used this code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the reason for the problem and it seems a bug to me.

When I put a `col-md-pull-0` for my `col-md-push-3`, Bootstraps tries to remove the left positioning from the element using `left:0` and sets the `right:25%` and strangely the left positioning does not work in this situation and I have to set the left to auto (`left:auto`) for it to work.

Keeping this in mind, the Bootply here "[Sample code](http://www.bootply.com/116880)" corrects the problem when I set the left to auto manualy.

If this is really the reason I'm using the classes correctly, this might be a bug in Bootstrap 3 and needs to be fixed.

Please let me know if this is what I think or not.

<del>**Update 1:** Here is a quick fix for this issue for now, before this will be fixed in the framework later **(It is not working fully as expected right now, I'm still working on it)** :</del>

<del>.col-xs-pull-0 {
      right: auto;
    }
    .col-xs-push-0 {
      left: auto;
    }
    @media (min-width: 768px) {
      .col-sm-pull-0 {
        right: auto;
      }
      .col-sm-push-0 {
        left: auto;
      }
    }
    @media (min-width: 992px) {
      .col-md-pull-0 {
        right: auto;
      }
      .col-md-push-0 {
        left: auto;
      }
    }
    @media (min-width: 1200px) {
      .col-lg-pull-0 {
        right: auto;
      }
      .col-lg-push-0 {
        left: auto;
      }
    }</del>

<del>Include this code in a css file and include that file after bootstrap.*.css in your HTML to fix this issue.</del>

**Update 2:** Finally I found the correct way of fixing this issue.

The part of Less code inside the mixin.less file from bootstrap framework, should be replaced by the code provided here:

**Find this code inside the mixin.less file (Problematic code):**

```
.calc-grid-column(@index, @class, @type) when (@type = push) {
  .col-@{class}-push-@{index} {
    left: percentage((@index / @grid-columns));
  }
}
.calc-grid-column(@index, @class, @type) when (@type = pull) {
  .col-@{class}-pull-@{index} {
    right: percentage((@index / @grid-columns));
  }
}
```

**And replace it with this code (Solution code):**

```
.calc-grid-column(@index, @class, @type) when (@type = push) and (@index > 0) {
  .col-@{class}-push-@{index} {
    left: percentage((@index / @grid-columns));
  }
}
.calc-grid-column(@index, @class, @type) when (@type = push) and (@index = 0) {
  .col-@{class}-push-0 {
    left: auto;
  }
}
.calc-grid-column(@index, @class, @type) when (@type = pull) and (@index > 0) {
  .col-@{class}-pull-@{index} {
    right: percentage((@index / @grid-columns));
  }
}
.calc-grid-column(@index, @class, @type) when (@type = pull) and (@index = 0) {
  .col-@{class}-pull-0 {
    right: auto;
  }
}
```

And this will fix the problem as much as I have tested it for now. Please let me know if anyone finds sometime wrong.

Also for those who are not familiar with Less and how to use it to customize and generate the bootstrap framework, you can find my article about this here ([How to customize Twitter Bootstrap to fit your web design](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/594098/How-to-customize-Twitter-Bootstrap-to-fit-your-web)).

Comment: I submitted this as an issue to Bootstrap github as issue #12854 and will wait for an answer.

Comment: I committed the fix to bootstrap's github. Hope they pull it soon.

Comment: If you look at the first entry in this thread, the columns and push ad pull, though they use the older LESS code from 3, work well with RTL with the push and pull. https://github.com/ratnic/bootstrap-rtl/issues/27#issuecomment-36232258. Just layout LTR and it will turn into RTL

Comment: The bug is not just affecting the RTL or LTR layouts by the mean of float to right instead of left or vice versa, either way you try the layout RTL or LTR, if you use the pull and push system and try to reset the position using the 0 pull or push, you will encounter the problem. You can see for yourself from Sample Code I provided.

Answer (score 0):

Also note one thing you dont need to repeat all these class

```
<div class="col-md-12 col-lg-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
```

By declaring col-xs-12 you are saying to bootstrap use 12 col for Mobile and bigger screen

```
<div class="col-xs-12">
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I see what you are mentioning here and I always use this approach but in fact, the code above is a work in progress and is not complete. I was working on the code but didn't go further when I encountered this problem and submitted the code here as it was.